# Google Script Overwriting Entire Sheet, Not Specific Range

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

In the function below, I grab data that is in multiple columns via a form response on my second sheet and place the information on my first sheet organized in rows.

I would like to have the first blank column after the data, currently G on my new sheet editable so that someone can come in and "approve" the contents of each row.  Right now, when this script runs, it overwrites the contents of Column G.  I thought the number 6 in the line with sh0.getRange(2, 1, aMain.length, 6).setValues(aMain); was telling the script to only put data into 6 columns... looks like that's not the case.

I also thought that I may be able to do a workaround by changing that line to sh0.getRange(2, 2 ... it would let me keep the first column as an editable column... that didn't work either.

Any suggestions to allow me to use this script and keep a column editable?

```
function SPLIT() {


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0 = ss.getSheets()[0], sh1 = ss.getSheets()[1];

  // get data from sheet 2
  var data = sh1.getDataRange().getValues();

  // create array to hold data
  var aMain = new Array();

  // itterate through data and add to array
  // i is the loop, j=3 is the column it starts to loop with, j<9 tells it where to stop.
  // in the aMain.push line, use data[i][j] for the rows to search and put in the one column.

  for(var i=1, dLen=data.length; i<dLen; i++) {
    for(var j=5; j<9; j++) {
      aMain.push([data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][j]]);
    }
    // add array of data to first sheet
    // in the last line, change the last number to equal the number of columns in your final sheet.
    // the first number in getrange is the row the data starts on... 1 is column.
  sh0.getRange(2, 1, aMain.length, 6).setValues(aMain);

   }
}
```

Comment: The above code does not delete/overwrite contents of column G. Perhaps, this is not the entire code you are running and the problem lies elsewhere. The problem is definitely not in the above code. The only improvement in the code is to move `sh0.getRange(2, 1, aMain.length, 6).setValues(aMain);
` outside the second for loop (look for where the for loop end ends '}').

Comment: In addition, `sh0.getRange(2, 1, aMain.length, 6).setValues(aMain);` means that values will be set from A2 to F? (where ? is however many rows your array `aMain` has). The 3rd variable is the number of rows starting at the 1st variable, and the 4th variable is the number of colums starting at the column in the 2nd variable

Comment: Thank you both... it looks like you're right.  I had two other functions running that I thought would have nothing to do with what was happening but when I disabled those, it no longer changed my column G.  Thanks!